# Stuck on "<path> attribute d: Expected number" error for D3 stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm pretty new to both Javascript and D3, so I may be overlooking something obvious here.

What I'm trying to do:

- Create a stacked area chart from a JSON file of fictional company
  data
- Use the variable "team" as the key for d3.stack
- Plot the "units_sold" variable on the y-axis

The JSON file is quite long, but here's a sample:

```
  [
    {
        "call_duration": 489.6,
        "call_revenue": 2971,
        "category": "furniture",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 62
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 395.5,
        "call_revenue": 7288,
        "category": "appliances",
        "company_size": "large",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "south",
        "units_sold": 1901
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 152.5,
        "call_revenue": 1528,
        "category": "materials",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "midwest",
        "units_sold": 608
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 162.29999999999998,
        "call_revenue": 4864,
        "category": "electronics",
        "company_size": "large",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 215
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 144.5,
        "call_revenue": 3704,
        "category": "materials",
        "company_size": "large",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 1649
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 151.5,
        "call_revenue": 1936,
        "category": "electronics",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "south",
        "units_sold": 155
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 134.4,
        "call_revenue": 2466,
        "category": "electronics",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 200
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 252.8,
        "call_revenue": 2645,
        "category": "furniture",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 93
    },
    {
        "call_duration": -84.6,
        "call_revenue": 1353,
        "category": "electronics",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 146
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 135.5,
        "call_revenue": 579,
        "category": "appliances",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "northeast",
        "units_sold": 325
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 35.2,
        "call_revenue": 1504,
        "category": "furniture",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "south",
        "units_sold": 70
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 208.5,
        "call_revenue": 1536,
        "category": "materials",
        "company_size": "medium",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "south",
        "units_sold": 474
    },
    {
        "call_duration": 168.5,
        "call_revenue": 784,
        "category": "materials",
        "company_size": "small",
        "date": "19/12/2017",
        "team": "west",
        "units_sold": 191
    }
```

Below is my .js code:

```
let margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#stacked-area")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y")

let x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const regions = ["west","south","northeast","midwest"];

let stack = d3.stack(); 

let area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d[0]); }) 
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
  
let plotArea = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("data/calls.json").then(data => {    

    cleanData = data.map((d) => {
      d.call_duration = +d.call_duration;
      d.call_revenue = +d.call_revenue;
      d.units_sold = +d.units_sold;
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      return d
    })

  x.domain(d3.extent(cleanData, function(d) { return d.date; })); 
  y.domain([0, d3.max(cleanData, function(d) { return d[`units_sold`] * 1.05; })]);
  colors.domain(regions); 

  stack.keys(regions); // .keys is a built-in method for d3.stack 

  let layer = plotArea.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(stack(cleanData)) 
    .enter() 
    .append("g") 
    .attr("class", "layer"); 
  
  layer.append("path")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.key); }) 
      .attr("d", area);

  plotArea.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  plotArea.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));      
});
```

But when I run the code above, I get the following error:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M710,NaNL710,NaNL710,…".

Again, I'm sure I'm just overlooking something basic, but I've been puzzling over this for a while now and am completely stumped. If anyone could help me figure this out, I'd appreciate it! Many thanks.

Comment: How do you want to go from your data to a stacked area chart? Do you only want to group by the `team` attribute or some others too?

Comment: I think I just want to group by team for now. (i.e. I want to keep it simple until I can figure out what simple mistake I made).